# CakePHP: Retrieve specific table field in controller

Tags: cakephp

I am new to Cake and tried to find the best solution to retrieve a specific field belonging to an $id:

This is my view function in my Post controller

```
function view($id = null) {
    if (!$id) {
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid post', true));
        $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
    }
    $this->set('post', $this->Post->read(null, $id));
}
```

In the post table, there is a user_id foreign key. I need to retrieve this specific field belonging to this Post $id.

I read about functions as find('All), read() or just drop an unconventional session in the view through:

```
$session->write('example') = $post['Post']['user_id];
```

What is the best way to do this, my preference is to retrieve the field in the controller. Thanks!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

CakePHP has a **field** function which should do just that.

```
$this->Post->id = $id;
$user_id = $this->Post->field('user_id');
```

For more information on using field, see: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#model-field

A second option is to use the **find** function and returning only a few fields if you do not want the entire Post object. Also shown below is using a condition instead of setting the current Post.

```
$this->Post->find('first', array(
  'conditions'=>array('id'=>$id),
  'fields'=>array('user_id')
));
```

More information on find is available at: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html

Comment: Great. Using CakePHP the find and field functions are used all the time so it's worth reading up on them including the Complex Find Conditions: http://book.cakephp.org/view/1030/Complex-Find-Conditions

Comment: Thanks Ryan, will check it out. Just rode that Find() will be replaced with createQuery in Cake 2.0

Comment: Thanks for the note, that is a big syntax change considering in our code we use "find" very often.

Comment: I really really really really wish `field()` was higher up the list in Cake's documentation... would have saved so much time.

Comment: **For CakePHP 3.*** , try this `->contain(['Languages' => [
    'fields' => ['BooksLanguages.book_id', 'Languages.id']
]]);` . More reading https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/issues/7913

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> $this->Post->id = $id;
> $this->Session->write('example',$this->Post->field('user_id'));
> ```

Comment: Was not aware of the `Model->field()` method.  Thanks for info.  Should probably dig through the Cake API more...but alas.

Comment: yep, there's also `saveField('field_name',value)` ;)

Answer (score 1):

In CakePHP 3, you can use `$this->Model->get()` to get the Entity, and then reference the required field directly.

```
$fieldValue = $this->ModelName->get($id)->fieldName;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, since I don't know which field(s) you need I provide an example field array set using Magic Find Types:

```
$fields = ['title', 'body', 'created'];
$record = $this->Post->findById($id, $fields);
```

or multiple records

```
$recordSet = $this->Post->findAllByTitle('The title', $fields);
```

*Note the the second example doesn't make a lot of sense unless there are multiple titles with the name 'The title' in the the posts.title column.