# Cakephp Unconventional Session

Tags: session, cakephp-2.0

Hi Im a newbie in cakephp and I found something unusual in cakephp2.x session. Can somebody explain to me what does this session code means:

```
$session->write('example') = $post['Post']['user_id];
```

I already know the basic syntax of session which is:

```
//controller
$this->Session->write('Person.eyeColor', 'Green');
//This writes the value ‘Green’ to the session under Person => eyeColor
```

but couldn't figure out what does the first code means.
PS sorry for the dumb question, still figuring out cakephp. Thnx

Comment: Is first code snippet even works? This kind of write to session is not docummented. You can try `var_dump(get_class($session));` and check if this is the same as `var_dump(get_class($this->Session));`. `$session` might be different type of object.

Comment: I don't know, I've just read it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6868016/cakephp-retrieve-specific-table-field-in-controller. okay i'll try that.

Comment: Then it won't work. `$session` is probably undefined. Code that You can see in the question You provided, is just proposition of solution.

Comment: ok instead, thank you for providing an explanation. Long live!